# Add strikethrough to checked checkbox

Tags: css, checkbox, twitter-bootstrap-3, forms, strikethrough

I am trying to add strikethrough when i select a checkbox in my form (Bootstrap v3).  I coded this [bootply](http://www.bootply.com/lQqTOQL9qu):

```
<div class="form-group ">
    <label for="inputName" class="col-md-1 control-label">select</label>  
    <div class="col-md-5">
        <div class="checkbox">
             <label><input type="checkbox" name="packersOff" class="strikethrough" value="1">sssssssss</label>
        </div>
     </div>
</div>
```

and added a class in css

```
.strikethrough:checked{
  text-decoration:line-through;
}
```

but it doesn't work..

Comment: i didn't have space, i wrote it wrong here. I edited the question

Comment: Where are you trying to add a strike through to? the input or the text?

Comment: Are you looking for a Javascript solution as well?

Comment: to the text @Andrew. In `ssss`

Comment: I would prefer sth with css.. but if you have a solution with javascript or jquery why not..

Comment: put the class on the label not the input

Comment: @Andrew is right but unfortunately there is not parent selector in CSS. Check my answer for a solution.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Here is a solution to put a strike through when your input is checked:

```css
input[type=checkbox]:checked + label.strikethrough{
  text-decoration: line-through;
}
```

```html
<div class="form-group ">
    <label for="inputName" class="col-md-1 control-label">select</label>  
    <div class="col-md-5">
        <div class="checkbox">
            <input type="checkbox" name="packersOff" id="packers" value="1"/>
            <label for="packers" class="strikethrough">sssssssss</label>
        </div>
     </div>
</div>
```

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/h9qqa46L/)

With this solution when ever the checkbox is checked it will do something to the label. so you could make it bold or change its colour if you wanted.

Answer (score 7):

Problem is that you are trying to apply `line-through` on checkbox where as the text is inside the label. You can wrap the text inside a `<span>` and alter it's CSS on `:checked`

```
<div class="checkbox">
   <label>
      <input type="checkbox" name="packersOff" class="strikethrough" value="1">
      <span>sssssssss</span>
   </label>
</div>




.strikethrough:checked + span{
  text-decoration:line-through
}
```

[Bootply](http://www.bootply.com/X5cUPLtbyP)

Answer (score 2):

```css
.strikethrough:checked + .strikeThis {
  text-decoration: line-through
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="form-group ">
  <label for="inputName" class="col-md-1 control-label">select</label>
  <div class="col-md-5">
   
      <input name="packersOff" class="strikethrough" value="1" type="checkbox">
      <label for="packersOff" class="strikeThis">sssssssss</label>
    
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

> The `:checked` CSS pseudo-class selector represents any radio (`<input
>   type="radio">`), checkbox (`<input type="checkbox">`) or option (`<option>`
>   in a `<select>`) element that is checked or toggled to an on state. The
>   user can change this state by clicking on the element, or selecting a
>   different value, in which case the :checked pseudo-class no longer
>   applies to this element, but will to the relevant one.

Source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3Achecked

In order to make it work, rearrange your HTML to:

```
<div class="form-group ">
    <label for="inputName" class="col-md-1 control-label">select</label>  
    <div class="col-md-5">
        <div class="checkbox">
          <input name="packersOff" class="strikethrough" value="1" type="checkbox">
          <label for="packersOff">sssssssss</label>
        </div>
     </div>
</div>
```

And your CSS to:

```
.strikethrough:checked + label {
  text-decoration:line-through
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://www.bootply.com/TQPgPlRsSh).

Answer (score 0):

jQuery solution:

```js
$('#packersOff').change(function() {
  if ($('#packersOff').prop('checked') ) {
    $('#test').css('text-decoration','line-through');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group ">
 <label for="inputName" class="col-md-1 control-label">select</label>  
    <div class="col-md-5">
  <div class="checkbox">
            <label for="packersOff" id="test">sssssssss</label>
            <input type="checkbox" name="packersOff" id="packersOff" class="strikethrough" value="1" />
        </div>
     </div>
</div>
```

Comment: woha - what an overkill

Answer (score -1):

This worked for me.

```
li.my-item:hover span { visibility: visible; }
li.my-item span { visibility:hidden; }
```