# Chart.js: Change lengend colors to array

Tags: javascript, arrays, chart.js

I have a chart with three datasets [(Svelte REPL with code and result)](https://svelte.dev/repl/ff38382900174e8586ff9ca70f042ec6?version=3.46.4) and would like to change the background colors of the boxes corresponding to each set, for example:

```
let legendColors = ['#dddddd', '#aaaaaa', '#777777'];
```

After several attempts the closest I got was changing font color, but not even that as array, only a single one. :(

How do I get the boxes of the legend to be in the 3 colors I want?

Thank you in advance for your help!

**Edit:** I did find something here: [What happened to generateLegend() in chartjs 3.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64759502/what-happened-to-generatelegend-in-chartjs-3-0), but that removes the functionality of the legend (i.e. removing parts of the data).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Edit: Another answer below has running snippet that is simpler to implement which also answers OP's request. My original answer below is more focused on building the legend completely by oneself.

---

[Live Demo](https://svelte.dev/repl/6837683bca0248abae9804757b75cb19?version=3.46.4). I've found this is fun...

Some points to note:

1. <strike>You need to **build the legend** yourself, as your colors are not "relevant" to the data you use (that's why by default it is using the colors from dataset "a")</strike> (edited as another answer shows such possibility)
2. As you are using Svelte, in the Demo I used the `<style>` which binds with the `<div>` for the legend for styling of the legend.
3. For people who ain't using Svelte, or are seeking solutions within Chart.js, they should follow the advice from the [StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64759502/what-happened-to-generatelegend-in-chartjs-3-0) OP linked -- they need to **build the legend** using the `plugins` field of 2nd argument when creating a `new Chart()`

No matter which route to take, to keep the functionality of the legend as OP mentioned, I added a tweaked version of [default behaviour of OnClick](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/configuration/legend.html#custom-on-click-actions).

P.S. For (3) we have to further override `generateLabels()` ([here](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/configuration/legend.html#legend-label-configuration), but may cause `meta.controllers._resolveAnimation` having problems, which we may still need to override `onClick`).

P.P.S. When a legend item is clicked, the label is crossed out (strikethrough) as a default behaviour. That is left as a further exercise or another answer. (For Svelte, use Boolean flags to change styles. Alternatively, hack with [CSS checked checkbox labels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30975459/add-strikethrough-to-checked-checkbox)).

Comment: This is perfect - thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this in 2 ways, using a custom generateLabels function or by specifying a backgroundcolor in the dataset.

Custom generateLabels:

```js
let legendColors = ['#dddddd', '#aaaaaa'];

const options = {
  type: 'line',
  data: {
    labels: ["Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange"],
    datasets: [{
        label: '# of Votes',
        data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
        borderColor: 'pink'
      },
      {
        label: '# of Points',
        data: [7, 11, 5, 8, 3, 7],
        borderColor: 'orange'
      }
    ]
  },
  options: {
    plugins: {
      legend: {
        labels: {
          generateLabels: function(chart) {
            const datasets = chart.data.datasets;
            const {
              labels: {
                usePointStyle,
                pointStyle,
                textAlign,
                color
              }
            } = chart.legend.options;

            return chart._getSortedDatasetMetas().map((meta, i) => {
              const style = meta.controller.getStyle(usePointStyle ? 0 : undefined);
              const borderWidth = Chart.helpers.toPadding(style.borderWidth);

              return {
                text: datasets[meta.index].label,
                fillStyle: legendColors[i],
                fontColor: color,
                hidden: !meta.visible,
                lineCap: style.borderCapStyle,
                lineDash: style.borderDash,
                lineDashOffset: style.borderDashOffset,
                lineJoin: style.borderJoinStyle,
                lineWidth: (borderWidth.width + borderWidth.height) / 4,
                strokeStyle: style.borderColor,
                pointStyle: pointStyle || style.pointStyle,
                rotation: style.rotation,
                textAlign: textAlign || style.textAlign,
                borderRadius: 0, // TODO: v4, default to style.borderRadius

                // Below is extra data used for toggling the datasets
                datasetIndex: meta.index
              };
            }, this);
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
}

const ctx = document.getElementById('chartJSContainer').getContext('2d');
new Chart(ctx, options);
```

```html
<body>
  <canvas id="chartJSContainer" width="600" height="400"></canvas>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/3.7.1/chart.js"></script>
</body>
```

Adding background color prop in datasets:

```js
const options = {
  type: 'line',
  data: {
    labels: ["Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange"],
    datasets: [{
        label: '# of Votes',
        data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
        borderColor: 'pink',
        pointBackgroundColor: 'pink',
        backgroundColor: '#dddddd'
      },
      {
        label: '# of Points',
        data: [7, 11, 5, 8, 3, 7],
        borderColor: 'orange',
        pointBackgroundColor: 'orange',
        backgroundColor: '#aaaaaa'
      }
    ]
  },
  options: {},
}

const ctx = document.getElementById('chartJSContainer').getContext('2d');
new Chart(ctx, options);
```

```html
<body>
  <canvas id="chartJSContainer" width="600" height="400"></canvas>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/3.7.1/chart.js"></script>
</body>
```